# multiply row from one dataframe with matching column in another dataframe and add

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

say i have 2 dfs:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame( {'spot': [1,2,3], 'ID1': [0,1,0], 'ID2': [1, 1, 2], 'ID3': [0,0,1]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame( {'ID': ['ID1','ID2','ID3'], 'prop1': [0.01,0.8,0.0], 'prop2': [0.0, 0.04, 0.5]})
df1
   spot  ID1  ID2  ID3
0     1    0    1    0
1     2    1    1    0
2     3    0    2    1
df2
    ID  prop1  prop2
0  ID1   0.01   0.00
1  ID2   0.80   0.04
2  ID3   0.00   0.50
```

i'm struggling to figure out how to multiply the values from each colID in `df1` with the matching rowID from 'df2'.

As an intermediary, the idea is that i would end up with something like: (it won't actually be this, but this is the best way to display what i'm aiming for)

```
   spot        ID1                ID2             ID3
0     1         0           [1*0.8, 1*0.04]        0
1     2   [1*0.01, 1*0.0]   [1*0.8, 1*0.04]        0
2     3         0           [2*0.8, 2*0.04]  [1*0.0, 1*0.5]
```

And I ultimately want to end up with a (spot, prop1, prop2) dataframe where all the (newly) multiplied values of `prop1` and `prop2` are added in each row, as in:

```
   spot  prop1            prop2 
0     1 (1*0.8)          (1*0.04)    
1     2 (1*0.01 + 1*0.8) (1*0.04)    
2     3 (2*0.8 + 0)      (2*0.04 + 1*0.5)
```

I'm already stuck on the first multiplication bit... i tried:

```
arr = df1.iloc[:, 1:].to_numpy()
arr2 = df2.iloc[:, 1:].to_numpy()

for i in range(len(arr)):
    for j in range(len(arr)):
        print(arr[i, j] * arr2[i])
```

but it's not returning what i'm expecting...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can do:

```
df1.set_index('spot') @ df2.set_index('ID')
```

Output:

```
      prop1  prop2
spot              
1      0.80   0.04
2      0.81   0.04
3      1.60   0.58
```

Reset index if you like.